# Record center organizer rule changing metadata of documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, records-center, content-organizer-rule

I have a record center that is used for my send to connection to archive documents in my farm. I have created a content organizer rule to move documents to specific document libraries based on their contenttype. The rule works. My documents are moved to their designated libraries.

I do see a weird behaviour and that is that for all my documents the modifiedby field gets the value of the account that has created the content organizer rule. In this case my user account. Also the modified and created date get changed.

Shouldn't the modifiedby and other field keep the values from the document source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why I get a different user account. In site settings -> Content Organizer Settings there is a field called rule managers. The account that is configured here is the user that will by set in the modified by field of my items. In a default record center this is the SharePoint system account. In my case my record center is created with a script while logged in with the testacount, The account that creates the record center will be placed here as rule manager.

[image: Content Organizer Settings]